# Eloquent: How to access related model within a withDefault() closure?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

There is a BelongsTo relationship with Client model in my Invoice model. Both models have an `email` field, but Client represents detailed information when it exists.
Here is how I get a list:

```
$invoices = Invoice::with('client');
```

and I use `$invoice->client->` when represent information. I need to set `$invoice->client->email` into `$invoice->email` in case if there's no client found. `->withDefault()` method works fine, but I can't get a real client's email, which is exist in Invoice model.

Here is my relation:

```
class Invoice extends Model {

/**
 * Get an invoice client.
 */
public function client() {

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Client', 'email', 'email')->withDefault(function ($client) {
        $client->email = $invoice->email; // How can I get an invoice email?
    });
}
```

version: `Laravel 5.5`

Comment: Could you describe what exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you have any invoices with no clients attached?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin  I have invoices with "client" attached, and I have invoices without any "client". All invoices have an email field, but not the all clients exists with the same email. I need to get $invoice->client->email correctly in both cases.

Comment: Please check the answer. I've tested it and it works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've said some invoices do not have a client and you want to email from the current model and not parent one. Use `$this` in the closure to access to the `Invoice` model properties:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Client', 'email', 'email')->withDefault(function ($client) {
    $client->email = $this->email;
});
```

But it doesn't work with eager loading. In this case, you can do this by using the `optional()` helper:

```
optional($invoice->client)->email ?? $invoice->email
```

Or you could create [an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) in `Invoice` model:

```
public function getAnyEmailAttribute()
{
    return optional($this->client)->email ?? $this->email;
}
```

And use it:

```
$invoice->anyEmail
```

Comment: It was first thing I tried. $invoice->client->email returns NULL :(

Comment: @AlexeyAlshenetsky works for me. I've tried to use `created_at` property from current model and `$model->parent->created_at` returned `$model->created_at`. What does `dd($invoice->client);` show for an invoice without a client?

Comment: It shows output with #attributes: array:1 [▼
    "email" => null
  ]

Comment: @AlexeyAlshenetsky if you do this in Tinker, rerun it after you change the relationship code. If you do this `$client->email = $this;` it should show you whole `Invoice` object in an array when you do `dd($invoice->client)`.

Comment: Yes, it shows me whole `Invoice` object. With empty `attributes` set and `exists: false`

Comment: @AlexeyAlshenetsky weird. It [works for me](https://ibb.co/gMy8Mm) in 5.5

Comment: Have you tried it with eager loading? I mean `with()` method. If I remove `:with('client')` condition, it works just like yours

Comment: @AlexeyAlshenetsky just tried, it doesn't work with `with()`. Shows `null`.

Comment: @AlexeyAlshenetsky it works without eager loading. With eager loading you could do this `optional($invoice->client)->email ?? $invoice->email` if it's an option.

Comment: @AlexeyAlshenetsky I've also added a solution with an accessor. It should work fine with eager loading.

Comment: A single accessor does not make any sense: invoice email is always the same as client's email and always correct. Thank you anyways. I decided to make a method in Invoice model that returns all the existing client's info.

Comment: @AlexeyAlshenetsky well, this accessor will check client email first and only then will use invoice email.

Comment: This example worked for me as a failover for when a relation is not found, it will always default to the main relation. Thanks @AlexeyMezenin, `withDefault` is what I was looking for :)